# where to place common jars in tomcat v6.0 server, which will accessible by all the apps deployed?

Tags: java, tomcat, jar

in tomcat 5 we used to place the commonly used jar in {HOME}/common/lib folder but in tomcat 6.0 the common folder has been removed. can somebody please tell me where to place the jars which will be loaded while sever started and which can be accessible by all apps deployed in server.

I have even created the {HOME}/common/lib folder and tried but it did not work. Also I tried placing the jars in {HOME}/lib but this also did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Tomcat 6 & higher, global libraries are place inside `TOMCAT_HOME/lib` folder. The `common/lib` was removed and `lib` was used instead.

Comment: Thanks Man, I have tried putting TOMCAT_HOME/lib but it didn't work, does any configuration require ??

Comment: @dku.rajkumar, no configuration is required. It works perfectly on mine. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Check here the apache documentation for [Class Loader](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html)

Comment: check this one as well http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_add_JARs_or_classes_to_the_common_classloader_without_adding_them_to_.24CATALINA_HOME.2BAC8-lib.3F