# MyEclipse Spring Tomcat different dev contexts, using html absolute URLS

Tags: jsp, tomcat, myeclipse

My local context is /123 and my work partners context is /456, when running simple HTML requests, like img src=/images, we want this to work across our shared projects. At the moment, that img tag would request localhost:8080/images rather than localhost:8080/[our-context]/images

We also need it to work with Javascript e.t.c, is there an easy way around this?

Cheers!

Comment: Your question is unclear. I'm not sure about the complexity of this problem. Please elaborate more. To me it sounds like as if `<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/foo.png" />`, or just by using the proper HTML base tag in combination with `<img src="images/foo.png" />` should do it for you. Does it really need to be `<img src="/images/foo.png" />` which you fiddle afterwards with JS? See also for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-css-and-images-when-calling-a-servlet-which-forwards-to-a-j/3658735#3658735

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Tomcat 6 & higher, global libraries are place inside TOMCAT_HOME/lib folder. [refer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238187/where-to-place-common-jars-in-tomcat-v6-0-server-which-will-accessible-by-all-t)
Try like this. I am not sure about the result.

Can you explain your question.. If you are making it more descriptive, you will get more answers.

[See this link](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html)